# Fast bidirectional bitshift?

Tags: c, optimization, bit-shift

I have a piece of code that gets executed a lot, which I would like to optimize. It looks like this:

```
int exponent;
uint32_t mantissa;

if (exponent < 0) {
    return mantissa << -exponent;
} else {
    return mantissa >> exponent;
}
```

It's purpose is quite clear, it should right-shift `mantissa` by `exponent` places, where `exponent` can be negative.

Is there a faster way to code this (without the branch if possible)?

Answer (score 4):

Sure there is. That is, a branch-free one; I wouldn't say it's necessarily faster in all circumstances.

```
int exponent;
uint32_t mantissa;

return (uint32_t)( (uint64_t)mantissa << (32-exponent) >> 32 );
```

Comment: I might have some other interesting info, `mantissa` is a 23 bits integer here, and exponent has the range [-127, +128]. (Yes, IEEE 754 :)).

Comment: +1: Clever.  I suppose there isn't a similar trick where the mantissa is bigger (64-bits) on a machine where the largest native type is also 64 bits long.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this one ["integer abs without branching"](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs). This guy has a great set of bit tricks including the one you want. Seems like in your case 'sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT' should just be substituted with 8, if 'exponent' variable type never changes.

By the way, are you sure that this particular 'if'-statement is the performance problem due to branching? What I mean is that there's no point in optimizing away the branches if the problem lies with poor data locality somewhere else.